# Resize Matrix Rows and Cols in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have imported data in MATLAB as a matrix called A with a size

48 x 52 (48 Rows X 52 Columns).

How do I RESIZE the matrix to 48 X 48 in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about losing whatever data is in those columns, you can delete the last 4 columns using

`A(:,49:52) = []`

Otherwise, I'd assign to a new matrix as HPM suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Well

```
B = A(:,1:48)
```

will make `B` a `48x48` matrix which matches part of `A`.  Is that what you want ?